# Beginners question - do i need to separate my class to different classes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a UIViewController class that do the following:

1. detect movement.
2. array a bunch of images and do some orders manipulation.
3. insert images to the view.
4. animate some images.

   - btw there are a lot of objects in the class (60).

do i need to separate some of this steps to different classes ?
if so why and to which class type.

tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel this is somewhat subjective, but personally I'd separate them as follows:

MODEL:

- array a bunch of images and do some orders manipulation.

VIEW:

- detect movement. (but only tell the controller, controller should react to the movement)
- animate some images.

CONTROLLER:

- insert images to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'll want to have separate classes for your model, view, and controllers.  Therefore if you'll usually have something like this:

MyViewController.m, MyView.m, MyModel.m

at the very least.  Note that if you build your view with IB then you'll have a MyView.xib file instead of MyView.m.

This would be only a beginning point however.  Depending upon the complexity of your app you'll probably wind up with many more classes that factor out common state and functionality.  In general it is a bad idea to put everything into one class.  This holds as much for any oo language as it does for objective-c

Comment: ok. so base on the following which step i will put in the model and controller (view i created in the IB).

Answer (score 0):

Might be an idea to get a book like [Beginning iPhone Development](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430216263).
As ennuikiller said iPhone applications are built using the model, view, controllers concept. The book bring you's up the core ideas of how to develop iPhone applications.